# Segmentation fault with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

I am getting a segmentation fault because of the assignment operation in LinearNode.cpp the line that reads `previous = node` in the setPrevious function.  Previous is declare as `LinearNode* previous;`  I could really use some help because I haven't used pointers in 3 years and can't remember much.   Thanks!

LinearNode.cpp

```
  #include<iostream>
#include"LinearNode.h"

using namespace std;

//Constructor for LinearNode, sets next and element to initialized states
LinearNode::LinearNode()
{
    next = NULL;
    previous = NULL;
    element = 0;
}//ends LinearNode default constructor

//Constructor for LinearNode takes an element as argument.
LinearNode::LinearNode(int el)
{
    next = NULL;
    previous = NULL;
    element = el;
}//ends LinearNode constructor

//returns the next element in the structure
LinearNode* LinearNode::getNext()
{
    return next;
}//ends getNext function

//returns previous element in structure
LinearNode* LinearNode::getPrevious()
{
    return previous;
}//ends getPrevious function

//sets the next variable for the node
void LinearNode::setNext(LinearNode* node)
{
    next = node;

}//ends the setNext function

//sets previous for the node
void LinearNode::setPrevious(LinearNode* node)
{
cout << "next" << node -> getElement() << endl;
    previous = node;
}//ends the setPrevious function

//returns element of the node
int LinearNode::getElement()
{
    return element;
}//ends the getelement function

//sets the element of the node
void LinearNode::setElement(int el)
{
    element = el;
}//ends the setElement function
```

LinkedList.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"LinearNode.h"
#include"LinkedList.h"

using namespace std;

//linkedlist constructor for an empty linked list
LinkedList::LinkedList()
{
    count = 0;
    contents = NULL;
}//ends the constructor

//adds an element to the front of the linked list
void LinkedList::add(int element)
{

    int found = 0, current = 0;

    for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
    {
        if (contents -> getElement() == element)
            found = 1;
        else    
        {

            contents = contents -> getNext();
        }//ends the else statement
    }//ends the while loop

    if ((found == 0) && (count == 0))
    {
        LinearNode *node = new LinearNode;
        node -> setElement(element);
        contents = node;
        count++;
print();
    }//ends the if statement
    else
    {

        LinearNode* node = new LinearNode ;
        node -> setElement(element);
        node -> setNext(contents);
        contents -> setPrevious(node);
        contents = node;
        count++;
print();
cout << endl;
    }//ends the found == 0 if statment
}//ends the add function

//this function removes one element from the linked list.
int LinkedList::remove(int element)
{
    int found = 0, result = 0; 
    LinearNode* previous;
    LinearNode* current;

    if (count == 0)
        cout << "The list is empty" << endl;
    else 
    {
        if (contents -> getElement() == element)
        {
            result = contents -> getElement();
            contents = contents -> getNext();
        }//ends the contents.getElement() == element
        else 
        {
            previous = contents;
            current = contents -> getNext();
            for (int index = 0; ( (index < count) && (found == 0) ); index++)
                if (current -> getElement() == element)
                    found = 1;
                else
                {
                    previous = current;
                    current = current -> getNext();
                }//ends the else statement 

            if (found == 0)
                cout << "The element is not in the list" << endl;
            else
            {
                result = current -> getElement();
                previous -> setNext(current -> getNext());
            }//ends else statement  

        }//ends the else stamtement

        count--;
    }//ends the else statement of count == 0
    return result;
}//ends the remove function


void LinkedList::print()
{
    LinearNode* current;
    current = contents; 

    for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
    {
        cout << current -> getElement() << endl;
        current = current -> getNext();
    }//ends the for loop
}//ends Print function
```

Comment: Are you sure the assignment is where the problem is happening? Did you use a debugger to come to this conclusion? If so, could you provide the line number where it's occurring?

Comment: I didnt use a debugger but when I `cout` something after the assignment it doesn't work

Comment: Well, keep in mind that `cout` is buffered - so it's possible that the output you're seeing is old, as the buffer wasn't flushed at the time of the crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're modifying `contents` which I believe is supposed to point to the head of your list.

```
contents = contents -> getNext();
```

When you iterate until `contents` is null (in `add()`) and then call anything that believes `contents` is non-null because `count>0` you have your crash.

First call to `add()`: count is 0, you create a `LinearNode *` and set `contents` correctly.

Second call to `add()`: count is 1, you scan by doing `contents = contents->getNext()` - ending up with `contents==null`. You then, since `(found == 0)` and `(count != 0)` create a new node, and call `contents->setPrevious()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but I did notice a place where a pointer could be null, which may result in a segfault:

```
//sets previous for the node
void LinearNode::setPrevious(LinearNode* node)
{
cout << "next" << node -> getElement() << endl;
    previous = node;
}//ends the setPrevious function
```

You don't check to see if `node` is actually null, or invalid, which it could be. Dereferencing a null or bad pointer could cause a segfault.

Comment: its definitely not null because i already tried that exact thing and there was an integer there

Comment: But are you sure that EVERY time you call this function, `node` isn't null?

Comment: yea because i just added `if node != NULL` and it still seg faulted

Comment: Hmm... so `node` must be pointing to a non-null location, but somewhere that's not a valid address. Can you print out the value of `node` (i.e. the address) and see where it's pointing at when it crashes?

Comment: Ok, so if you compare that to the addresses of `node` in other iterations, does it make sense, or is the address way different?

Comment: Edited the comment to be more specific about what I was looking for. Really, I'm looking for consistency in the addresses.

Comment: i was modifying the head pointer instead of a copy of it so when i was messing with the list i was at the last node instead of the first one like i thought